# How to merge a list of sentences with the same subject, containg adverbs, in a single one?

Tags: adverb, sentence-structure

I want to find an equilibrium between the following bad writing problems:

- excesively repeating a subject (*Hans ... Dannach hat Hans... Hans fand x gut.* usw.)
- making a too long sentence (which make my text unreadable, and in my case is a potential source of grammatical mistakes)

Thus, for sake of concreteness, suppose you have a list of sentences sharing a subject: *ich*. Let's choose the simplest possible ones:

> 1. Ich wache um 6.30 Uhr auf.
> 2. Ich bereite das Frühstück vor.
> 3. ...

Merging is still easy: *Ich wache um 6.30 Uhr auf, bereite das Frühstück vor, ...*.

But now add to some sentences adverbs, here for example, *in der Regel* to sentence **2**:

> 1. Ich wache um 6.30 Uhr auf.
> 2. In der Regel bereite ich um 6.40 das Frühstück vor.
> 3. ...

Then I don't know how to merge the sentces, for, on the one hand I want to write only once the subject and, on the other hand, *in der Regel* would take possition 1 after the comma. Is

> Ich wache um 6.30 Uhr auf, in der Regel bereite ich um 6.40 Uhr das Frühstück vor, ...

the only option? (wenn es überhaupt richtig wäre) I'd like to have a variant in which dropping the *ich* in the second sentence is possible.

Comment: Wo ist Hans? :)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz :D habe ich geändert, weil es denn möglich gewessen wäre, *Hans* durch *er* zu ersetzen. Jetzt ist *Hans* weg.

Comment: One of the main differences between adverbs and coordinating/subordinating conjunctions is that adverbs can move places. So if you have an adverb in 1 that means the same adverb can be somewhere else too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich wache um 6.30 Uhr auf; bereite in der Regel um 6.40 Uhr das Frühstück vor; gehe duschen, vorausgesetzt, dass das warme Wasser funktioniert; frühstücke; trinke noch einen Kaffee, falls der erste nicht gereicht hat; lese die Zeitung, wenn es wichtige Neuigkeiten gibt, und gehe hoffentlich nicht allzu verschlafen zur Arbeit.

Comment: Ach so, mach nichts, dass die Adverbien da sind. Danke.

Comment: Wobei hier stark zu empfehlen und auch erlaubt (§ 80) ist, die einzelnen Auflistungspunkte durch Semikola abzutrennen. Ich ändere das mal, da da eh noch ein paar Kommata fehlen.

Comment: Ich sehe kein Problem darin, diese gesamte Aufzählung mit Kommata zu trennen anstatt mit Semikola.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar das macht es halt einfacher die logischen Teile voneinander zu trennen, wenn man kein Muttersprachler ist